# Create a column in dataframe based on existing columns and conditions (Dealing with Warning)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am dealing with the following task:

"Create a new column in the dataframe. If the value of another column matches a fixed string, the new column takes the value of column_a, for any other case, the new column takes the value of column_b"

For this purpouse, i am using this piece of code:

```
df['new_column'] = np.where(df['colum_2_check'] == 'FIXED_STRING', df['column_a'], df['column_b'])
```

I am getting this warning when executing:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Is writing on a copy of a slice a bad practice? Is there a way to improve the proposed solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['FIXED_STRING', 1, 2], ['something_else', 3, 4]],
    columns=['colum_2_check', 'column_a', 'column_b']
)
idx = df['colum_2_check'] == 'FIXED_STRING'
df.loc[idx, 'new_column'] = df['column_a']
df.loc[~idx, 'new_column'] = df['column_b']
print(df)
```

prints

| index | colum_2_check | column_a | column_b | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | FIXED_STRING | 1 | 2 | 1.0 |
| 1 | something_else | 3 | 4 | 4.0 |